# Android Room Migration Testing AbstractMethodError onPreMigrate

Tags: android, android-room, android-testing

All Room dependencies are aligned to version `2.3.0`
I've added a Room DB migration and added two more columns to an existing table, it seems to work fine as no error appeared during normal operation.

I wanted to add some tests for the migration and did so following the official docs:
[Room DB Migration Testing](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/migrating-db-versions#test)
However this line:

```
db = helper.runMigrationsAndValidate(TEST_DB, 2, true, MIGRATION_1_2);
```

will throw a

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: abstract method "void androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper$Delegate.onPreMigrate(androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase)"
```

I went down the rabbit hole and indeed `androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper.MigratingDelegate` does not implement `onPreMigrate`

Does anyone have an actual sample with migration and testing showing off how it should work ?

Am I totally off or are the docs wrong already on the dependency:

```
testImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"
```

should probably be `androidTestImplementation`
since it's a on-device test ? Googling didn't serve any results, so does that mean that nobody actually uses the package ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the issue, it was Proguard/minification.
First I tried to disable it for the test-apk all together, by adding `testProguardFile 'proguard-test.pro'` to my build.gradle, with proguard-test.pro containing

```
-dontoptimize
-dontobfuscate
-keepclasseswithmembers class ** { *; }
```

(don't really need any minification for the test-apk) but that didn't do the trick.
Since androidx.room.testing.MigrationTestHelper.MigratingDelegate does not override `androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper$Delegate.onPreMigrate` the proguard rule has to actually go to the regular proguardFile (for the APK under test). I added

```
-keepclassmembers class androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper$Delegate { *; }
```

and it's working now.